# moving to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I moved my site to a new php 5.2 server with no access to apache conf files
So I had to put site's rewrite rules into an .htaccess (wildcards is open for the domain)
and I expirience a lot of issues with it now

ORIGINAL WAS

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
rewriteEngine on

rewriteCond $1 !^pages/
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com
rewriteRule (.*) /pages/%1/$1

rewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /pages/
rewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What changes Do I need to make ?

the whole point is that I need to redirect:
`www.mydomain.com/pages/XXXXX.php`   ==>
  `XXXXX.mydomain.com/...whatever....`

but also
`www.mydomain.com/pages/XXXXX/...whatever....`   ==>     `XXXXX.mydomain.com/...whatever....`

Answer (score 0):

The rules below should do what you requested.

However, in the first example, where does the `whatever` appear in the original request to `www.mydomain.com/pages/XXXXX.php`.

If the `whatever` refers to the query string, then it should work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
#redirect www.mydomain.com/pages/XXXXX.php to XXXXX.mydomain.com/
RewriteRule ^pages/(.+)\.php http://$1.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
#redirect www.mydomain.com/pages/XXXXX/.whatever.. to XXXXX.mydomain.com/...whatever
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/(.*) http://$1.mydomain.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^pages/
    RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)(?:\.php|/(.*))$ http://$1.mydomain.com/$2 [R=301,L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^pages/
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.mydomain\.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com
    RewriteRule (.*)           /pages/%1/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And one more: please make sure whether you REALLY NEED the `Options +FollowSymLinks` directive as this might cause an internal error if not allowed or already set in httpd.conf